# Onclick open posts displayed in slider in a popup

Tags: posts, plugin-development

In the attached image, the posts are displayed in a slider style. When I click on post in the slider, suppose CArd5, then the details should of that post eg: the thumbnail, excerpt etc should be displayed in the pop-up, the pop-up html code has been included in the end as " "

```
Function addcards()
    {
      $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'cards', 'post_status' => 'publish' ));
    ?>
    <body>

          <div id="demo">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                  <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">


    <?php
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) 
        {
        $the_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="item orange">
         <!-- <a href = "#modal">  -->
         <!-- href = "#modal" -->
         <form action="" method = "post">
          <a href = "#modal" id="<?php echo get_the_title();?>"  onClick="reply_click(this.id)" 
          class="lbp-inline-link-1 cboxElement" style="text-decoration:none">
        <!-- <div style="display: none;">
          <div id="lbp-inline-href-1" style="padding:10px; background: #fff;">
          <p>This content will be in a popup.</p>
          </div>
        </div> -->
        <div class="squarebox">
        <div class="innersquare">
        <div>
        <table>
        <tr>
          <td align="left"><p><?php echo get_the_author();?></p></td>
          <td align="left"><p><?php echo get_the_date();?></p></td>
        </tr> 
        </table>
        </div>

        <div>
        <h3><?php echo get_the_title();?></h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url();?>">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p><?php  the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Techmatters-125167747841183/" data-layout="button" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FTechmatters-125167747841183%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
        <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"> lang: en_US</script>
        <script type="IN/Share" data-url="https://www.facebook.com/Techmatters-125167747841183/"></script>


      </div>
      </div>
    </a>
    </form>
    <?php $postid = get_the_title(); ?>
      </div>


        <?php
        }
      ?>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 






    <script type="text/javascript">
    function reply_click(clicked_id)
    {
        var userID = clicked_id;
        alert(userID);

    }   
    </script>





    <!-- popup html -->

    <div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1Title" aria-describedby="modal1Desc">
      <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close" aria-label="Close"></button>
      <div>
        <h2 id="modal1Title" class="results">

         </h2>
        <p id="modal1Desc">
          Responsive, lightweight, fast, synchronized with CSS animations, fully customizable modal window plugin
          with declarative state notation and hash tracking.
        </p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <button data-remodal-action="cancel" class="remodal-cancel">Cancel</button>
      <button data-remodal-action="confirm" class="remodal-confirm">OK</button>
    </div>

    <?php
    }
    add_shortcode('cards','addcards');
    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: What is your specific problem? What did you expect, and what happened instead? What have you done to debug it?

Answer (score 1):

I am giving you an idea for this, you have to use jQuery for the popup and the below syntax will give you the current post data in a HTML popup.

```
 while ($the_query->have_posts()): $the_query->the_post(); 

        echo '<div class="non-popup">';
            echo '<div class="card-title" id="card-'.get_the_title.'">'.get_the_title().'</div>';
               write you front end code + html (http://screenshotlink.ru/eff3d7431f4fbcd6a03ca5fcbbc41cdd.png) 
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="popup" style="display:none;">';

           echo '<div class="popup-title">'.get_the_title().'</div>';

             write your popup html + code      

        echo '</div>';

endwhile;
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".card-title").on('click',function(){          
           $(this).siblings().css('display','block'); 
      });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

there are many ways to this but i suggest ajax for it. When you click on any post get the post_id and pass it to ajax function. Get id in ajax function(in function.php ) you called first and get post data. You can do two things on ajax sucess 1) append complete html( html for popup ) OR 2) just append  thumbnail, title,excerpt values in html